# Conversion error retrieving image from DB2 in MobileFirst SQL adapter

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to implement an SQL adapter which saves and retrieves data from a DB2 database. The issue I am getting is specifically related to retrieving an image.

I understand that generally the best approach is to base64 encode the image and store it in the database as a string and decode when you get it out of course.

As an initial test we have inserted an image into the database manually (as a CLOB) and are then trying to retrieve it using a stored procedure call (as opposed to an SQL select). Not sure whether either of these approaches are causing problem.

Anyway I see an image attribute coming out of the SP but I can't seem to do anything with it. So for example when I try to log it I get an error.

```
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project RPLRaffle]nullorg.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Invalid JavaScript value of type com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.pe (/integration.js#67)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:913)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:969)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError1(Context.java:932)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.errorWithClassName(ScriptRuntime.java:3964)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeof(ScriptRuntime.java:2530)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_9(/integration.js:67)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2016_02_02T13_44_35_050Z_241589205a2ecf6728217d40bb203e40eb65d619_RaffleSQLAdapter_impl_js_39._c_retrieveRaffleAndPrizes_3(2016-02-02T13:44:35.050Z/241589205a2ecf672
```

I followed [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/jsonstore_revisited_in_worklight_v6_part_1_the_adapter?lang=en) (in part at least)
which describes adding some config to the db2 driver properties. I have done this too but to no avail.

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be gratefully received... The code below is a snippet from the SQL adapter. The exception occurs on the line after the `Print image to log ...` statement

```
WL.Logger.warn("invoke procedure=" + JSON.stringify(procedure));
answer = WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure(procedure);

if (answer && answer.resultSet && answer.resultSet.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0, ilen = answer.resultSet.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        var prize = answer.resultSet[i];
        var clob = prize["PRIZEIMAGE"]; 
        WL.Logger.warn("Print image to log ...");
        **WL.Logger.warn(prize["PRIZEIMAGE"]);**
        WL.Logger.warn("... done");
        if (clob) {
            var bytes = clob.getBytes(1, clob.length());
            if (bytes) {
                prize["PRIZEIMAGE"] = bytes;
            }
        } else {
            WL.Logger.warn("image type=" + (typeof prize["PRIZEIMAGE"]));
        }
    }
} else {
    WL.Logger.warn("No results");
}
```

Comment: Why do you think "to base64 encode the image and store it in the database as a string" is the best approach? Why not store the binary image?

Comment: Based on other comments I've seen in StackOverflow e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349179/how-to-use-adapters-to-retrieve-sql-server-image-datatype-value

If there are better/other approaches I am open to suggestions because this wall is starting to hurt my head with all the banging.

Comment: @idan-adar I see you added tags to my question ... I was kinda hoping you would have an answer as I think the guidance (around base 64 encoding) in the related post was from you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have all the answers. :-)

Comment: booooooo ... I thought you were the font of all knowledge Idan :D

Comment: @KJTaylor, have you managed to resolve this question?